# TSQL: multiple split string in one query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a string_split function which looks like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[String_Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))
returns @temptable TABLE ([value] varchar(8000))     
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       
      
    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       
      
    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       
          
        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable([value]) values(@slice)       
  
        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

I am now successfully able to split the string using the below code

```
declare @NameList nvarchar(100) = 'Hi,Hi1,Hi2';
SELECT * FROM string_split(@NameList,',')
```

but now I want to split multiple string using the same function like below

```
declare @NameList nvarchar(100) = 'Hi,Hi1,Hi2';
declare @DESCLIST nvarchar(100) = 'Hii,Hii1,Hii2';
```

I want to split these strings in different columns,

my expected output is

```
col 1       col 2
------------------
 Hi     |Hii
 Hi1    |Hii1
 Hi2    |Hii2
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You do know there's a built in function called [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) , right?

Comment: @NooreenRizvi, change the function and return the ordinal position of each substring as a column in your table (`id` for eaxmple). Then you simply need `SELECT * FROM dbo.string_split(@NameList, ',') s1 JOIN dbo.string_split(@DescList, ',') s2 ON s1.id = s2.id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can join them on row-number.

```sql
SELECT
  s1.value,
  s2.value
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@NameList, ',') s
) s1
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DESCLIST, ',') s
) s2 ON s2.rn = s1.rn;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25fed1f4b739b71b398d326adbd32351)

I *strongly* suggest you store multiple items in separate rows, rather than a comma-separated list. Consider using a table variable, temporary table or Table Valued Parameter.

Comment: Azure-free boilerplate about [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) not guaranteeing the order of returned values until `enable_ordinal` is supported in SQL Server and the `ordinal` output column is used instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: @HABO I know, it's been said many times already. I am somewhat comfortable with it, because `ROW_NUMBER` always goes in a serial zone, and `STRING_SPLIT` always outputs the split in order, so if there are no intervening operators then it should be fine. In other words, as long as the `ROW_NUMBER` and `STRING_SPLIT` are in a derived table with *nothing else*, no joins or any other window function.

Comment: Glad to know that. If you'll provide a citation for the documentation I'll help spread the word. And let's get Microsoft to correct "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string." since it is, at best, misleading.